# Create a separate table based on select condition query in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using select query with condition to remove the duplicates. Query as below

```
select * from (
select LOCATIONID, OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC, max(ROW_KEY) ROW_KEY from OLD_TABLE group by LOCATIONID, OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC
)
```

here it will display only 3 columns and LOCATIONID, OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC,ROW_KEY out of 15 columns

I want to create a separate table which has all the columns and order of the columns should not be changed.

I tried below query

```
create or replace table NEW_TABLE as
select * from (
select LOCATIONID, OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC, max(ROW_KEY) ROW_KEY from OLD_TABLE group by LOCATIONID, OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC
)
```

but the above query gives only 3 columns, whereas I need the data as it is in new table(it should have all the columns).
could someone correct my query please!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your most inner SELECT doesn't select all 15 columns and on top of that uses a GROUP BY, so you can't really have that with your current statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify could be used to grab the highest row(row_key) per location and observation_time:

```
 -- create or replace new_table as
Select *
From old_table
Qualify row_number() over(partition by location_id, observation_time_utc 
                          order by row_key desc) = 1
```